# SQL Trigger access row's fields dynamically

Tags: mysql, triggers

Currently trying to have a generic activity log table that stores which table, field, value changed (+ necessary primary key)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_customers_insert_activity_log AFTER INSERT ON `customers`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

      DECLARE curr_column CHAR(255);
      DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT false;
      DECLARE column_name_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'customers' ORDER BY ordinal_position;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET finished = 1;

      OPEN column_name_cursor;
        column_loop: LOOP
          IF finished THEN
            LEAVE column_loop;
          END IF;
          FETCH column_name_cursor INTO curr_column;
          INSERT INTO activity_log(`cid`, `table`, `field`, `value`, `modified_by`, `modified_at`) 
            VALUES (NEW.cid, 'customers', curr_column, NEW.@curr_column, NEW.modified_by, NEW.modified_at);

        END LOOP column_loop;
      CLOSE column_name_cursor;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem I have is in here:

```
INSERT INTO activity_log(`cid`, `table`, `field`, `value`, `modified_by`, `modified_at`) 
            VALUES (NEW.cid, 'customers', curr_column, NEW.@curr_column, NEW.modified_by, NEW.modified_at);
```

Since I am dynamically looping through each field by name I don't know how I can get the NEW.@curr_column value. How can you access a property of the NEW/OLD objects using the value of a variable?

To clarify the syntax error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@curr_column, NEW.modified_by, NEW.modified_at); END LOOP column_loop' at line 17
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to dynamically address the NEW and OLD values within a TRIGGER.

---

We can use a CASE expression. But this probably isn't what you were looking for. It's not really "dynamic". We need to statically address each column name we're interested in.

```
  CASE curr_column 
  WHEN 'cid'       THEN NEW.cid
  WHEN 'foo'       THEN NEW.foo
  WHEN 'othercol'  THEN NEW.othercol
  END
```

---

Also problematic is the various datatypes of the columns you might want to store in `activity_log` table `value` column... DATE, INTEGER, DECIMAL, ENUM,  VARCHAR, ... those are all going to need to be cast to a single datatype of the `value` column.

Some alternatives to consider:

- have the trigger save a copy of the entire row
- rather than making the trigger "dynamic", make the creation of the trigger more dynamic... i.e. use a SELECT from information_schema.columns to assist in producing the contents needed in the trigger definition

Comment: Thanks as it turns out your second option is pretty close to my solution. Ended up making a node module that reads info schema columns/fields and creates an activity log + triggers to deal with automatically recording changes.

Unfortunately to make a single activity log work for a schema I had to set the data field to a long varchar, but since its for historical purposes and data recovery it should not be an issue.